# Join two context menus or bind a context menu item to a command of the parent view model

Tags: wpf

Let's say I have a `ListBox` with a few items bound to it.

The `ListBox` itself has a few `ContextMenuItem`s that are not dependent on a selected item (like "Add" or "Clear" or "Refresh").

Each item of the `ListBox` has `ContextMenuItem`s that are dependent on a selected item (like "Delete", "Edit" or "Show details").

Of course I'd like to be able to "Add" an item or "Refresh" the list, even if I right mouse clicked on an item of the `ListBox`.

So, here are my questions.

Is it possible to somehow add the `ContextMenuItem`s of the `ListBox` to the `ContextMenu` of each item, so that the user will have all possibilities, when right clicking on an item and only the fewer `ContextMenuItem`s of the `ListBox` in case he happens to right click on a part of the list that's not belonging to an item?

If I have to add these `ContextMenuItem`s of the `ListBox` manually (at design time) to the `ContextMenu` of the items, how do I bind a `ContextMenuItem` of an item of the `ListBox` to a `Command` in the view model of the `ListBox`?

Googling after the second part brought only solutions involving putting the `DataContext` of the list somehow in the `Tag` of the items and then binding to the `PlacementTarget`s `Tag`. But misusing the `Tag` seems a little hacky, I thought I left behind misusing the `Tag` when leaving VB6.

Here's a little bit of code:

MainViewModel.vb:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
    Private _refreshCommand As ICommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Me.Refresh)

    Public Sub New()
        _items = New ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Text = "Monica"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Text = "Ross"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Text = "Rachel"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Text = "Joey"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Text = "Phoebe"})
        _items.Add(New ItemViewModel With {.Text = "Chandler"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemViewModel)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property RefreshCommand As ICommand
        Get
            Return _refreshCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Refresh()
        MsgBox("List Refresh")
    End Sub

End Class
```

ItemViewModel.vb:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ItemViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _text As String
    Private _showCommand As ICommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Me.Show)

    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _text = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged("Text")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ShowCommand As ICommand
        Get
            Return _showCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Show()
        MsgBox("Item Show")
    End Sub

End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    x:Name="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_ContextMenuCommandTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem x:Name="mnuListRefresh" Header="List Refresh" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MainWindow}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="mnuItemShow" Header="Item Show" Command="{Binding ShowCommand}" />
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem x:Name="mnuItemRefresh" Header="Item Refresh" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.RefreshCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

</Window>
```

In this code I actually used the hacky `Tag` binding just for testing purposes. I hope for other solutions not involving the `Tag`.

Comment: What is your actual issue here? Do the bindings work or not?

Comment: Using the `Tag` they work, but I don't like to misuse the `Tag` in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Tag` property is a trick to get a reference to a `DataContext` that is not inherited by the `ContextMenu`. You can't use a `RelativeSource` to the window directly like this because the `ContextMenu` resides in its own visual tree and is thus not a descendant of the parent `Window` nor the `ListBox`:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.RefreshCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Your solution is perfectly fine. If you don't want to use the `Tag` property for some reason, you may create your own [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) and set and bind to this one instead.